# Im tried to test the android application i.e., WECHAT.apk automation testing using APPIUM technique

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, appium

I'm using APPIUM to test automatically WECHAT.apk. But while using appium server with eclipse IDE , I can able to test to open the file.

```
package com.qa.test;

 import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 import org.testng.Assert;
 import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
 import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

 import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
 //import org.junit.Test;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;



 public class appiumlogin {
    RemoteWebDriver driver = null;
    //private RemoteWebDriver webDriver;


 @BeforeTest
 public void beforeTest() throws Exception{
    //install ne apk
    try{
    //File appDir = new                         
      File("C://Users//SYS//Downloads//new//android//Android//sdk//platform-tools");
//File app = new File(appDir, "wechat.apk");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","emulator-5554");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.3.1");

   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.tencent.mm");
   capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.tencent.mm.ui.LauncherUI");


  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Test

public void wechatinstall(){
    WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.id("com.tencent.mm:id/cgw"));
    Login.click();
    WebElement LogIn = driver.findElement(By.id("com.tencent.mm:id/g0"));

    Assert.assertEquals("true", LogIn.getAttribute("enabled"));
    WebElement mobilenumber = driver.findElement(By.id("com.tencent.mm:id/bun"));
    Assert.assertEquals("true", mobilenumber.getAttribute("enabled"));
    Assert.assertEquals("9036103153", mobilenumber.getText());
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("com.tencent.mm:id/gz"));
    Assert.assertEquals("true", password.getAttribute("enabled"));
    Assert.assertEquals("lachudarling", password.getText());
    WebElement Login1 = driver.findElement(By.id("  com.tencent.mm:id/ac6"));

    Login1.click();
    Assert.assertEquals(" ", mobilenumber.getText());
    Assert.assertEquals(" ", password.getText());


 }

   @AfterTest
 public void afterTest() throws InterruptedException{
      driver.quit();


        }
    }
```

In this pgm i tested apk file it just opening a app. But doesnot selecting the login button.

Comment: Seems that "  com.tencent.mm:id/ac6", there's space before, that's why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot about the `perform`

```
Login1.click().perform();
```

Comment: Login1.click().performerror showing Multiple markers at this line